# Automatic mapping between Native C++ classes and WinRT Components (ref classes)?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

Suppose I have written my BL in pure, native C++ (for the expressed purpose of reusing it on other platforms), and now I want to expose certain classes as WinRT Components (so that I can write the UI in C#).

Is there any code generator that will automatically generate equivalent 'ref classes' (WinRT components) for a given native C++ class, and generate the mapping code of copying a set of properties from one to the other (sort of like what AutoMapper does for .NET POCOs?)

Comment: Not available.  Maybe some day but I wouldn't hold my breath for that.  The language projection works well enough from WinRT to C++/CX thanks to the limited set of types to deal with but not the other way around.  And tooling required to parse C++ reliably (like Edison's) costs an arm and a leg.

Comment: *"automatically generate equivalent 'ref classes'"* - `ref class`es are always reference counted. Given that property, there cannot be an equivalent `ref class` for every C++ class. Multiple inheritance in C++ also maps poorly to the WinRT type system. Unless your C++ implementation exposes its services through a well defined ABI (like COM), you cannot hope for any tool to step in and help out. COM TypeLibs, .winmd files, and .NET's metadata use a well defined ABI. That's why you can find automatic conversion tools for each of those.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool and it's not the idea of WinRT and Cx to need one. I'd say it's a part of your architectural responsibility in that native C++ logic.

How WinRT and C++ environment targeting Windows 8 helps you is:

- you can easily mix ISO C++ code with Cx/WinRT based C++ code, potential direction is a wrapper
- you can write WinRT component in 100% ISO C++ with using WRL and some COM magic that could help you rethink the BL to adapt it for the new target

Below links are pointers for WRL template library:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Camp/Developing-Windows-8-Metro-style-apps-in-Cpp/The-Windows-Runtime-Library-WRL-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh438466.aspx

Comment: with my StackOverflow reputation I cannot add more links in the main answer but below additional link represents similar request sent directly to Microsoft and Visual Studio people:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2274170-iso-c-wrappers-for-winrt

Comments there and additional link related to ABI may help you better understand the rationale.